# Does VSCode support being connected to multiple language servers for the same file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The normal use-case for language servers is that you're writing a source file in some programming language and the editor is connected to the language server for that one language.

But there are some use-cases where it would be useful to be connected to multiple language servers. For example, you might be writing a python template (eg: jinja2), which has both python and javascript code in it.

Does VSCode support this, and if so how?

Comment: If that was the case, they would've used that for HTML, right? Instead they have a single html lsp-server, and detect language context on the server side: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/7fd6f1b1d46bd2223a902406fccd20cc7a539825/extensions/html-language-features/server/src/modes/embeddedSupport.ts#L37